# Parsing Google Maps API results in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-maps, for-loop

I have written a script to parse the results from a Google Maps API results to get specific parts from it. In my specific case, I need geolocation. Here is the example of how the response from Google Maps is structured:

```
{'address_components': [{'long_name': '253',
   'short_name': '253',
   'types': ['street_number']},
  {'long_name': 'Broadway', 'short_name': 'Broadway', 'types': ['route']},
  {'long_name': 'Manhattan',
   'short_name': 'Manhattan',
   'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_1']},
  {'long_name': 'New York',
   'short_name': 'New York',
   'types': ['locality', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'New York County',
   'short_name': 'New York County',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'New York',
   'short_name': 'NY',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'United States',
   'short_name': 'US',
   'types': ['country', 'political']},
  {'long_name': '10007', 'short_name': '10007', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
 'formatted_address': '253 Broadway, New York, NY 10007, USA',
 'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 40.7133073, 'lng': -74.0073864},
  'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
  'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.71465628029149,
    'lng': -74.00603741970849},
   'southwest': {'lat': 40.7119583197085, 'lng': -74.00873538029151}}},
 'place_id': 'ChIJ9wzTpBhawokRWLkRYU6k64E',
 'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'PX7V+82 New York, United States',
  'global_code': '87G7PX7V+82'},
 'types': ['premise']}
```

And here is my code

```
def get_geocode(address_data):
    for item in address_data['location']:
        typs = set(item['types'])

        if typs == set(['premise']):

            return item['location']

    return None
```

Could you suggest a better way to parse the results? As I understand, the sets only divvy up the dictionaries inside the first list inside address components, so I'm not quite sure how to parse everything that comes after it.

The output I would like to get is: 'lat': 40.7133073, 'lng': -74.0073864, either separately or in one line.

Comment: can you add your expected output, you tag as pandas but not sure how you want the final structure

Comment: With `item['location']` you should already get a one-liner `{'lat': 40.7133073, 'lng': -74.0073864}`. Can you describe the exact problem and expectation please?